# Missed var before "I" in cycle or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, global-variables, tic-tac-toe

I have some javascript code while trying to code a tic tac toe game, but  chrome developer tool gives this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
I've found that when I comment  'isEnd(bigArray[i][j]);' in the end of the code, it works.
Code:

```js
var inputItem = 'o';
var board = [null, null, null, null, 'o', null, null, null, null];
var sign = {
  max: inputItem === "o" ? "x" : "o",
  min: inputItem === "x" ? "x" : "o"
};

function generateTable(board, sign) {
  var testBoard = [],
    nextBoard;
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    nextBoard = board.slice();
    if (!nextBoard[i]) {
      nextBoard[i] = sign;
      testBoard.push(nextBoard);
    }
  }
  return testBoard;
}

function isEnd(board) {
  console.log('board', board);
  for (i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
    if (board[i] === board[i + 1] && board[i + 1] === board[i + 2]) {
      return board[i] !== null ? board[i] : false;
    }
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
    if (board[j] === board[j + 3] && board[j + 3] === board[j + 6]) {
      return board[j] !== null ? board[j] : false;
    }
  }

  if ((board[4] === board[0] && board[4] === board[8]) ||
    (board[4] === board[2] && board[4] === board[6])) {
    return board[4] !== null ? board[4] : false;
  }
}

function miniMax() {
  var testBoard = generateTable(board, sign.max);
  testBoard = testBoard.map(function(elem) {
    return generateTable(elem, sign.min);
  });
  return testBoard;
}
var bigArray = miniMax();
console.log(bigArray);


var maxArray = 0;
var tempArray = 0;
var maxCoord = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < bigArray[i].length; j++) {
    console.log('i, j: ', i, " ", j);
    isEnd(bigArray[i][j]);
    maxCoord = i;
    if (tempArray > maxArray) {
      maxCoord = i;
    }
  }
}
```

the result is

```
i, j:  0   0 Script snippet #21:22  
board ["x", "o", null, null, "o", null, null, null, null] Script snippet #21:57  
i, j:  6   1 Script snippet #21:22
board [null, "o", null, null, "o", null, null, "x", null]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the function:

```
function isEnd(board) {
```

you have this line:

```
for (i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
```

So the i variable is global.

Change this line to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
```

Example:

```js
var inputItem = 'o';
var board = [null, null, null, null, 'o', null, null, null, null];
var sign = {
  max: inputItem === "o" ? "x" : "o",
  min: inputItem === "x" ? "x" : "o"
};

function generateTable(board, sign) {
  var testBoard = [],
      nextBoard;
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    nextBoard = board.slice();
    if (!nextBoard[i]) {
      nextBoard[i] = sign;
      testBoard.push(nextBoard);
    }
  }
  return testBoard;
}

function isEnd(board) {
  console.log('board', board);
  
  //
  // This is the only line changed
  //
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
    if (board[i] === board[i + 1] && board[i + 1] === board[i + 2]) {
      return board[i] !== null ? board[i] : false;
    }
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
    if (board[j] === board[j + 3] && board[j + 3] === board[j + 6]) {
      return board[j] !== null ? board[j] : false;
    }
  }

  if ((board[4] === board[0] && board[4] === board[8]) ||
      (board[4] === board[2] && board[4] === board[6])) {
    return board[4] !== null ? board[4] : false;
  }
}

function miniMax() {
  var testBoard = generateTable(board, sign.max);
  testBoard = testBoard.map(function(elem) {
    return generateTable(elem, sign.min);
  });
  return testBoard;
}
var bigArray = miniMax();
console.log(bigArray);


var maxArray = 0;
var tempArray = 0;
var maxCoord = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < bigArray[i].length; j++) {
    console.log('i, j: ', i, " ", j);
    isEnd(bigArray[i][j]);
    maxCoord = i;
    if (tempArray > maxArray) {
      maxCoord = i;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks now I get it. Creepy IDE - always recommends me to remove 'var' because the variable was already assigned. :>>

Answer (score 0):

It's because `board` in `isEnd()` is undefined. Check what you're sending it.

Perhaps you want to send `bigArray` rather than `bigArray[i][j]`.

Comment: But it is not always undefined:  
    
    `i, j:  0   0`  
    board ["x", "o", null, null, "o", null, null, null, null]  
    i, j:  6   1  
    board [null, "o", null, null, "o", null, null, "x", null]  
    
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Ah, ok. Please include that in the original question along with as much detail as you have about the situation when you actually hit the error.